# How to retrieve a specific message by ID (tried fetch_message(id))

Tags: python, bots, discord, message, discord.py

```
@client.command()
async def edit(ctx, message_id, *, new_message) :
    channel, chan, guild = None, list_channels("saved_channels.csv"), ctx.guild.id
    message = await fetch_message(message_id)
    await message.edit(new_message)
    embed=discord.Embed(color=0x00ca1f)
    embed.add_field(name="Success :white_check_mark:", value=f"Le message a bien été édité dans {message.channel.mention}", inline=False)
    await ctx.send(embed = embed)
```

I'm trying to edit a specific message my bot sent in another channel by taking the message id with `fetch_message()` (supposed to be in the new discord API) but it gives me the `NameError: name 'fetch_message' is not defined`... is there something I did wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the channel where bot should edit the message from.

For example,

```
channel = client.get_channel(channel_id)
message = await channel.fetch_message(message_id)
```

Also, when editing a message you need to specify the content as follows:

```
await message.edit(content=new_message)
```