# I can't find out how to use fetch_message properly, discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

I've been looking for solutions to fix this issue for 2 hours now, so i decided to sign-up and ask here. The fetch_message() method doesn't form the message_id into the actual message. Also i tried to use the get_message method which is outdated. What i'm going to do it use this message and add the user who add a reaction to its String value. The ERROR:

AttributeError: 'Bot' object has no attribute 'fetch_message'

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

TOKEN ="******"

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix=".")
channel = client.get_channel(796410027455283220)

days = ["monday", "tuesday", "wednesday", "thursday", "friday"]

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("logged in")

    @client.event
    async def on_message(message):
        if message.author == client.user:
            return

    @client.event
    async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload):
        message_id = payload.message_id
        msg = await client.fetch_message(message_id)

        user_id = payload.user_id
        user = client.get_user(user_id)

        await msg.edit(content=msg + user)





    @client.event
    async def on_reaction_remove(reaction, user):
        channel = reaction.message.channel
        await channel.send('removed scrim')


client.run(TOKEN)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to retrieve a specific message by ID (tried fetch\_message(id))](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61718475/how-to-retrieve-a-specific-message-by-id-tried-fetch-messageid)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`fetch_message` is a method on channel objects, not the bot client. So you need to get the channel first.

```
channel = bot.get_channel(payload.channel_id)
message = await channel.fetch_message(payload.message_id)
...
```