# Edit the last message that the bot sent discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

I've been looking around the web to see how I can make the bot edit its last message.

```
if message.content.lower() == 'edit':
  await message.channel.send('testing')
  channel = bot.get_channel(message.channel.id)
  message = await channel.fetch_message(message.id)
  await asyncio.sleep(3)
  await message.edit(content="the new content of the message")
```

But it just raises this

```
Ignoring exception in on_message

Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/home/runner/FluidLuxuriousCertifications/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 343, in _run_event
await coro(*args, **kwargs)
    File "main.py", line 708, in on_message
message = await channel.fetch_message(message.id)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'fetch_message'
172.18.0.1 - - [19/Apr/2022 10:39:21] "HEAD / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

I've done this so I can implement a timer feature into my bot and tried this code to test it so it can edit the message as the timer goes down.

Thanks

Comment: Did you try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61718475/how-to-retrieve-a-specific-message-by-id-tried-fetch-messageid)?

Comment: Based on the exception, bot.get_channel(message.channel.id) doesn't seem to be returning anything (None).
Check if get_channel(message.channel.id) for the bot object has a return .

Comment: @ChaoticNebula yeah, I did try that, but it's using ctx and I am using message.

Comment: @Thennan  I tried that, but it returns: name 'get_channel' is not defined.

Comment: @Lemm1ngs I meant to check the code block for get_channel. get_channel seems to be a  method for bot object. so you will be able to call bot.get_channel and not get_channel directly.

Comment: @Thennan it doesn't seem to report anything apart from 'Bot' object has no attribute ' channel'

Answer (score 0):

I found out the answer finally,
I used:

```
if message.content.startswith('edit'):
  test = await message.channel.send('not edited') # Defined message
  await asyncio.sleep(2) # Wait 2 seconds
  await test.edit(content='Edited') # Edit it
```

Thanks for your help though.